# How to use same tree after use it in same function in Haskell Recursive Function

Tags: haskell, if-statement, recursion, tree

```
data HuffmanTree 
   = Empty 
   | Intermediate Integer HuffmanTree HuffmanTree 
   | Leaf Char Integer
   deriving (Show,Eq)

decode :: HuffmanTree -> [Char] -> [Char]
decode (Intermediate n x y) (z:zs) = 
   if ..... (some checks for x,y,z)..... 
   then [getChar x] ++ (decode (Intermediate n x y) zs)
```

in this function I m moving on a tree. At "then" part I take deepest Leaf's x and after "++" I should give whole input tree again.The problem is : After ++ part still my function accepts my current tree (deepest leaf's parent). How to fix it ? (I can't change the type of decode, because it is predefined at homework)

Comment: Answer helped a lot . I guess it is the only way.(Already tried let-in structure and other tricks but all fail)

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the original tree along as an additional parameter:

```
decode' :: HuffmanTree -> HuffmanTree -> [Char] -> [Char]
decode' (Intermediate originalN originalX originalY) (Intermediate n x y) (z:zs) = 
  if ..... (some checks for x,y,z)..... 
  then [getChar x] ++ (decode' (Intermediate originalN originalX originalY) (Intermediate originalN originalX originalY) zs)
```

so that you have access to the whole input tree at any point.

Comment: What prevents you from having a `decode` with more than one parameter?

Comment: And why, exactly, did you delete your first comment to my answer so that now I look like an idiot who is talking to myself?

Comment: is it so important ? I delete it before refleshing page so didnt see your answer to my comment . Take it easy man it is stupid question. Maybe max 10 person will see it ^^ Btw I succeed to apply your way to my program and it worked  !! Thnx so much

Comment: "is it so important ?"

It is only important if you care about being nice to other people. 

"I delete it before refleshing page so didnt see your answer to my comment ."

Really? Then how did you manage to reply to my question which you "did not see"?

"Btw I succeed to apply your way to my program and it worked !!" 

Perhaps you should mark my answer as accepted?

"Thnx so much"

You are very welcome.

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer to your own question without having to vote it up.